# How to turn off checks on a per-file or per-function basis?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I am wondering what the best approach is to turn off some clang-tidy checks for either a given file or for a given function. For example, I want to turn on multi-thread warnings for the whole project, but I have a simple tool that uses the library that is single threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Clang-tidy doesn't make this really easy.

You can use `line-filter` option for this, without specifying the line ranges it can filter whole files. There is a catch however - this option filters files/line ranges IN so to exclude a file you have to specify everything else but that file (wildcards are supported but you'd have to name/suffix your files strategically).

To filter out functions you can either use `//NOLINT` or `//NOLINTNEXTLINE` or `line-filter` again with specified line ranges. The first two are okay if you don't need them in too many places. `line-filter` with specified line ranges is possible but clumsy to configure and easy to break when introducing code changes that add/remove lines.